# Twilio Download Recording and Transcribe of call using PHP RestAPI?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

As from the question it is quite clear what I am trying to achieve. What I had tried till now to achieve the said is:

**dailcall.php**

```
$call = $twilio->calls
    ->create($to, // to
    $from, // from
        [
        "method" => "GET",
        "url" => "https://twilioxxxx.tk/api/araonvlad_bot/recording.php",
        "record" => true,
        'transcribe' => true,
        "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
        "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("in-progress completed"),
        ]
);
```

**recording.php**

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
require DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$twilio = new Client("AC8b2cc96be2a8dbc059f29xxxxx", "88db8eeb71124a3effd6c19681xxxx");
if($_REQUEST['CallStatus'] == 'in-progress') {

    file_put_contents('request.log', "\n" .json_encode($_REQUEST). ' - in-progress recording start now : - ' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $callSid = $_REQUEST['CallSid'];
    $recording = $twilio->calls($callSid)
                    ->recordings
                    ->create([                               
                        "recordingStatusCallback" => "https://twilioxxxxxx.tk/api/araonvlad_bot/read_Recording.php",
                        "recordingStatusCallbackEvent" => ["completed"],
                        "recordingChannels" => "dual",
                        'transcribe' => 'true'
                     ]
                );
    file_put_contents('request.log', "\n" .json_encode($recording). ' - in-progress recording variable : - ' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

}
```

**read_Recording.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$twilio = new Client("AC8b2cc96be2a8dbc059f2908e8xxxxx", "88db8eeb71124a3effd6c196xxxx");
file_put_contents('request.log', "\n" .json_encode($_REQUEST). ' - read Recording File: - ' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

if I set `transcribe= true` in the `dailcall.php` it shows `500 error`. how I can start recording in recording.php file as I am getting error. All three files are on same level with vendor folder added with composer.

How I can get the recording download mp3 file and the transcribtion of recording. I have recording just about 30 seconds max.

I had read the documentations: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-record-phone-calls/php 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-recording-metadata
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording-transcription

Comment: @philnash please assist me!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for [creating a call with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) or [creating a recording for a live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource) you will see that `transcribe` is not an option to either API. You can only transcribe a single leg of a call using the [`transcribe` attribute on the `<Record>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#transcribe).

To perform transcription on a call that has more than one participant, you can use one of the transcription add-ons like Watson Speech to Text or VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription which you can [enable in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/product/voice?category=recording-analysis).

Comment: I am trying to achieve in recording.php file with the recording attribute. What I am trying is 1. dial the call 2.  in-progress event start recording from recording.php that has transcribe attribute too as you mentioned. 3. get recording mp3 file and transcribe of the recording. @philnash

Comment: OR How I can achieve this task in twiml? By dailing call sending dtmf and record and transcribe call. @philnash

Comment: Twilio doesn't transcribe a call between two people. You can use an add-on to do this, as I suggested, but you cannot apply a `transcribe` attribute to a call using the REST API.

Comment: Can I use `transcribe="true"` on `<Dial transcribe="true">` Like this???  As I am making outbound call. @philnash

Comment: No. Twilio doesn't transcribe a call between two people. If you want to transcribe a call like that, you will need to use an add-on. If you cannot find the attribute or property in the documentation, then Twilio does not support it.

Comment: Many thanks I got it Sir. Then How `<Record transcribe="true">` work? Is this not working with the dail call? Mean I want to dail the call and start recording after recording trranscribe it

Comment: `<Record>` is a single leg call in which one person can record a message. You are asking about connecting people via `<Dial>`, which does not have a `transcribe` property, or making calls via the REST API, which also does not have a transcribe option. With Twilio you can only transcribe a single leg of a call recorded via `<Record>` and if you want to transcribe other calls you will need to use an add-on.

Comment: Many thanks for clarify my concepts. So I can record the call from rest api too. After recording I can use the add-on for transcribe right?

Comment: You can [read more about how to use transcription add-ons in PHP here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons/tutorials/how-to-use-recordings-add-ons-in-php).